# Should I close the gable vent on my garage in the winter?

Tags: garage, winterizing

My garage has a vent grill similar to [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Builders-Edge-18-in-x-24-in-Rectangle-Gable-Vent-in-Bright-White-120061824117/100669288). The vent is near the roof on the outside wall where I have my garage doors. I do have 1/2 of the walls insulated and I was planning to start finishing the insulation on the garage.

[image]

Do I need to do anything on the winter to prevent cold air to the garage? Or is it ok to leave as is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, vents are there precisely to be open in the winter (and all other seasons) and plugging them up may result in various problems depending on which of various roles they serve, including but not limited to combustion air supply for fuel-burning appliances, keeping the roof from forming ice dams, preventing mold and mildew, etc.

As such, even without further details about what this particular one is doing, I would tend to think that it was put there precisely because there is supposed to be a vent there, usually to meet building code, and it should not be plugged.